# C# XNA - 'Game' is a 'namespace' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#

I don't understand how to fix this problem, what am I suppose to change 'Game' too?

```
 namespace Game {

    public class Help : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent
    {
        public Help(Game game): base(game)
        {
           // TODO: Construct any child components here
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization code here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // TODO: Add your update code here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 8):

Rename your namespace 'Game' to something like MikesGame:

```
 namespace MikesGame {

    public class Help : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent
    {
        public Help(Game game): base(game)
        {
           // TODO: Construct any child components here
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization code here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // TODO: Add your update code here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }
    } 
 }
```

Comment: But if I do that I get this error: The type or namespace name 'MyGame' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Mike: You do something wrong. @Den's code has nothing about `MyGame`

Answer (score 4):

Game is your namespace, just as the error suggests.

```
namespace Game {
```

Your attempting to pass in an object also called Game

```
public Help(Game game)
```

You either need to change your namespace to be something other than your object name, or fully qualify your object 'Game' if you have an object under another namespace called Game. e.g

```
public Help(AnotherNamespace.Game game)
```

Answer (score 2):

You named your namespace "Game" which collides with the built in XNA type, `Game`.  Change `Game` to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game` **or** rename your namespace to something else.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use your namespace of `Game`, then for everytime you want to use the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game` class, you'll need to specify the full namespace `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is the Game namespace as it is the same as the Game object type and the compiler can't differentiate them. Change the name of the namespace.